# How to inspect OData Command collection in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Web API service exposing an OData API resource. The flow of logic is simple: the `Get()` method calls the repository to get all (people) and the filtering as a result from the OData commands on the query string happens automatically in my API controller because of the OData configuration.

However, my `People` resultset is getting large so I've implemented caching of that (since it's mostly static and only updates daily) and it works well. At some point though I may need to place the filtering that came as a part of the OData request to the repository query, rather than pulling back the entire dataset and *then* doing the filtering.

At code camp recently I thought it was mentioned that you could get access to the OData commands used on the API call, and it would require a manual interpretation of these and applying them manually on the query.

Is there a way to see what OData commands exist on the API call in the controller so that I can eager filter my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually on further review I found there is a much easier way to extract and inspect the query options. When trying to use the `ODataQueryOptions` parameter in the `GET` call I ended up with the following error:

> ```
> Multiple actions were found that match the request
> ```

According to [ASP.NET WebAPI OData - Inheriting from EntitySetController<> but using Get(ODataQueryOptions options) rather than [Queryable]Get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392677/asp-net-webapi-odata-inheriting-from-entitysetcontroller-but-using-getodata) this is because `EntitySetController` already defines a Get method. However `EntitySetController` defines a `QueryOptions` parameter I was unaware of that is accessible directly as shown below and the easiest way to inspect the OData command parameters:

```
public override IQueryable<Pharmacy> Get()
{
    //Inspect the query options passed in on the query string
    var opts = this.QueryOptions 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options under "Invoking Query Options Directly". Instead of using the Queryable attribute, you can have an alternate signature which gives you access to the options, which gives you information about the query being performed.

Comment: The article it was linked to was also good in practice: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/02/25/translating-odata-queries-to-hql.aspx